# Derivative of power function when power itself is a function

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Imagine we have two function f(x) and g(x). I'm interested in computing the derivative of
$$\frac{d}{d_x}(f(x)^{g(x)})$$

What is the easiest and most computationally robust of computing this derivative?

Comment: Write it as $e^{g(x)\log f(x)}$, then use the chain rule.

Comment: What if f(x) <= 0 ?

Comment: In that case replace $g$ by $1/g$ and $f$ by $-f$. If $f$ is identically $0$ in a neighborhood, the derivative there is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $h(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}$, then we have
\begin{align*}
\log h(x)&=g(x) \log f(x)\\
\frac{h'(x)}{h(x)}&=g'(x)\log f(x)+g(x)\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\\
h'(x)&=h(x)\left[g'(x)\log f(x)+g(x)\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right]\\
h'(x)&=f(x)^{g(x)}\left[g'(x)\log f(x)+g(x)\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right]
\end{align*}

Comment: what if h(x) (or f(x)) is less than or equal to 0?

Comment: @Sam If $f(x)$ is not positive the function $h(x)$ is not well defined (in real numbers). Since we are playing with differentiable (then continuous) functions. If $g$ is not constant in $\Omega=Dom f\cap Dom g$, then the image $g(\Omega)$ contains at least one interval $]a,b[$, in which we can find an element of the form $p/2$ with $p\in\mathbb Z_{\neq 0}$, let $x_0\in\Omega$ such that $g(x_0)=p/2$. Therefore, $h(x_0)=(f(x_0))^{p/2}=\displaystyle\left(\sqrt{f(x_0)}\right)^{p}$ is well defined?

Comment: @Sam For example think in $h(x)=(\sin x)^{\cos x}$ and you take $x=4\pi/3$. You will see my previous comment in action.

Answer (score 1):

$
h(x)=e^{g(x)\log f(x)}\implies h'(x)=h(x)\left(g'(x)\log f(x)+ g(x)\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)
$
Alternatively,
$\log h(x)=g(x)\log f(x)$
And differentiate with respect to $x$

Comment: As I commented above, how about the cases where f(x) is less than or equal to 0?